# ASP.NET MVC5 + Razor Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My app was working fine and **suddenly** it started giving me this frustrating error.

Have no idea why... even if I return `null` from `_GetTags` it still gives me the error.

```
    public PartialViewResult _GetTags(int articleid)
    {
        var alltags = _db.SelectAll();
        var thisarticletags = from tat in alltags
            where tat.ArticleID == articleid
            select tat;

        return PartialView("_GetTags", thisarticletags.ToList());
    }
```

I call that action in a strongly typed view like this:

```
 @{ Html.RenderAction("_GetTags", "AdminArticleTags", new { articleid = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] }); }
```

As I mensioned, it was working just fine. Now it simply doesn't. The thing is I can't even debug it line by line because program execution doesn't stop at my breakpoints at `_GetTags`, it simply gives an `System.Web.HttpException` exception where I use `RenderAction` to call the partial view.

```
System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
  Source=System.Web
  WebEventCode=0
  StackTrace:
       at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
       at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage)
       at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
       at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, Object routeValues)
       at ASP._Page_Views_AdminArticles_Edit_cshtml.Execute() in c:\users\vahid\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ClearBlog\ClearBlog\Views\AdminArticles\Edit.cshtml:line 183
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
       at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.
       Source=System.Web.Mvc
       StackTrace:
            at System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
            at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
            at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndProcessRequest>b__9()
            at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3()
            at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap[TResult](Func`1 func)
            at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action)
            at System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
            at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride)
       InnerException:
```

**Edit:**

There is nothing wrong with the script. Thanks to FrancescCastells, The problem was figured out. I described it in the comments.

Comment: Do you use authentication? is it possible that your child action is redirecting due to a not authorized request (caller not authenticated)?

Comment: @FrancescCastells Yes!, And that WAS the problem. For testing purposes I commented out one of my authentication attributes and forgot to uncomment it. Thanks.

Comment: Good. I'm glad it's solved.